# Get part of a page with Ajax not using .load

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I see a lot of similar examples on here but can't seem to tweak them to work for me. I am creating a landing page by loading content from other URLS. But I don't want the entire html content, just what is inside of a div called 'main-wrapper'. I'm not using .load() because I wanted to run some code after the divs load and .load() was causing some other problems with javascript not working.

This code does load the content, but instead of finding and loading the .main-wrapper div, it just loads the entire page. I've tried like a thousand variations and just can not figure it out.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'mydynamicurl.html',
dataType: "text", // "html"
success: function(response) {
    $('#load').html(response).find('.main-wrapper');
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get this from the page, i believe you would need:`var contentRequired = $(response).find('.main-wrapper').html();`
Then, set this html via: `$("#load").html(contentRequired);`

Edit: Just to clarify, the reason I believe it was not working previously, is due to the fact that you were setting the HTML value of the '#load' div to be that of the response. Then, upon this, you were then searching the '#load' div to find the 'main-wrapper' content.

Alternatively, you could write:

```
$('#load').html($(response).find('.main-wrapper').html());
```

However, I find that this doesn't read aswell. Had to edit this answer, and update, as I forgot to actually set the returned value of the find method to be that of the HTML contents.

EDIT:
If your div is a 'top-level element', then it seems that the 'Find' method will not work. Instead, the 'filter' method should be used, as so:

```
$('#load').html($(response).filter('.main-wrapper').html());
```

Comment: This makes sense, I tied it both but no luck. No content is imported in. No error in the console. I logged the variable and it just came back as undefined.

Comment: Does logging the variable from, $(response).find('.main-wrapper') return an undefined object?

Comment: it does return an undefined object. Do I need all this is a document ready call?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see you replied yesterday. I've created a JsFiddle with, what I believe, to be the desired result. Is this what you are intending to do? https://jsfiddle.net/yu7bLo80/

Comment: Thank you for this. I think your code is correct, but it is still not working on my site.I must be missing something. When I use your code, I just get nothing no errors. I'm trying to pull the section ".main-wrapper" from http://lido.pointbdev.com/local-beach-house.html and http://lido.pointbdev.com/southern-california.html to show up here: http://lido.pointbdev.com/hotel/  @Joel, can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, so, I've worked it out via debugging for your site. It's due to the fact that your div is a top level element. Use 'filter' instead of 'find'. E.g., change var content = $(response).find('.main-wrapper').html(); to var content = $(response).filter('.main-wrapper').html(); This works for me when running locally

Comment: This works. Makes sense. Thank you. Tell me if I should make a new post for this, but my jQuery (for stuff like slide shows) works on the individual pages, but not the page with the ajax call. What is the proper way to load jQuery so if works after the divs have been loaded?

Comment: Are the divs dynamically generated? The $(function() syntax will only run when the document has loaded all elements, and then bind to them if relevant. However, they will not 'rebind' if elements are added at a later time. When I get time tomorrow, I'll append a jsFIddle to explain.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/JoelAndHowe/jpbqph2t/ here. How event binding works in jQuery, and why your content may not be binding

Comment: That makes sense. I'm going to play with this for a while and then will maybe open up a new thread. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like : `$(response).find('.main-wrapper')`

You can load string html into the `$(...)` :)

Comment: the unwrap was for something else all together. I removed it from my question. Basically just need to get the .main-wrapper div and not the entire page

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use document.querySelector('.main-wrapper') instead of find?

Comment: No familiar with that. I tried but same results. Loads the entire page.

Comment: document.querySelector('.main-wrapper').innerHtml() ??